# How to calculate total price using django?

Tags: python, django

I have simple django code, but it doesn't work. The code works to calculate total price from price and qty of the item purchased, then save it into the database.
Column total_price can't input in database, the database is null.
Here the code

```
class Items(models.Model):
    items_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    harga = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.items_name
class Transaction (models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def total_price(self):
        total = self.qty * self.items.harga
        return total
    total_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(total_price)
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? Can you update that to the question

Comment: Where are you creating the transaction object? If you want to save the `total_price` as a field you should calculate it and pass it in creation or override the save method. Otherwise you could use a `@property`.

Comment: One question: is better store it total on database, or calculate as a @property ? How to define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to calculate total_price when you need it rather than 
store it as column, so you can query it like this:

```
class Transaction (models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

```
Transaction.objects.annotate(total_price=F('items') * F('qty'))
```

Comment: it is almost correct, you need to use `F('items__harga')` here. :)

Comment: How do i call the function in my views or template ?